# How to handle if else in Dart Future

Tags: dart, google-drive-api

I need to get Google Drive a folder's fileId. If the folder does not exist, I need to create a folder with that name and return fileId. With fileId, I need to do other works.

The Google Drive API in Dart is ok for me, I can create a folder with Dart. The question is about Future.
The code is as follow:

```dart
  drive.files.list(q:"title='TEST'").then((result){        
    if(result.items.length == 0) {
      driveclient.File file = new driveclient.File.fromJson({"title":"TEST", "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"});
      drive.files.insert(file).then((result2) {
        return result2.id;           
      });
    } else {
      return result.items[0].id;
    }
  });
```

When TEST exists, the id is returned. But if TEST doesn't, the function error because no return.

How to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the future from the then method you call in line 4:

```dart
drive.files.list(q:"title='TEST'").then((result){        
  if(result.items.length == 0) {
    driveclient.File file = new driveclient.File.fromJson({"title":"TEST", "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"});
    return drive.files.insert(file).then((result2) {
      return result2.id;           
    });
  } else {
    return result.items[0].id;
  }
});
```

then() returns a new future there completes with the value returned from the method you give as parameter to the method. then() is also smart enough to resolve all nested future's so you will always handle a value inside a then() method and never a instance of Future.